# How to evaluate $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}e^{2n-n^2}?$

Tags: calculus, limits

How to evaluate $\;\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}e^{2n-n^2}\,?$

Hello, sorry if this is a simple limit to evaluate but I'm having a hard time doing this. I've tried using the natural log to solve this limit but I seem to in a loop where I get $\;\ln(y)=2n-n^2.$

Thank you.

Comment: You should be getting $\ln(y) = 2n - n^2$. The right hand side clearly goes to $-\infty$ as $n \to \infty$. (Try graphing it to see why.)

Comment: Dunno how rigorous you need to get, but $n^2\gg 2n$ at large $n$, therefore $e^{2n-n^2}\sim e^{-n^2}\sim 0.$

Comment: Note that $e^{2n-n^2} = 1/(e^{n^2-2n})$. Now, the denominator goes to $\infty$ as $n \to \infty$, so…

Comment: If $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = b$ and $\lim_{x \to b} g(x) = c$, and either $g$ is continuous at $b$ or $f(x) \ne b$ on some neighborhood of $a$, then $\lim_{x \to a} g(f(x)) = c$. (the continuity of $g$/avoidance of $b$ by $f$ condition is needed since $g(b)$ need not be $c$ in general). This is true even when $a$ or $b$ = $\pm\infty$ (where in the latter case, we have $f(x) \ne \pm\infty$ on a neighborhood of $a$, so "continuity of $g$ at $\pm\infty$" is not a concern).  Since you know that $\lim_{x \to -\infty} e^x = 0$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} 2n-n^2 = -\infty$, this is a direct application.

Answer (score 0):

$$\large \lim_{n \to \infty} e^{- n^{2} + 2 n} = e^{\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(- n^{2} + 2 n\right)} $$

Multiply and divide by $n^2$:

$$\large e^{ \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(- n^{2} + 2 n\right)}  = e^{\ \lim_{n \to \infty} n^{2} \frac{- n^{2} + 2 n}{n^{2}}} $$

$$\large e^{ \lim_{n \to \infty} n^{2} \frac{- n^{2} + 2 n}{n^{2}}}  = e^{ \lim_{n \to \infty} n^{2} \left(-1 + \frac{2}{n}\right)} $$

$$\large e^{ \lim_{n \to \infty} n^{2} \left(-1 + \frac{2}{n}\right)}  = e^{ \lim_{n \to \infty} n^{2} \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(-1 + \frac{2}{n}\right)} $$

$$\large e^{\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{2}  \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(-1 + \frac{2}{n}\right)}  = e^{\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{2}  \left(- \lim_{n \to \infty} 1 + \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2}{n}\right)}=e^{\infty}=\infty $$
Hence
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{2} = \infty, \qquad \lim_{n \to \infty} e^{- n^{2} + 2 n} = 0 $$